# Python complex sorting of a list by multiple attributes with condition

Tags: python, sorting

The challenge is from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSBLe8cKu0s&feature=youtu.be

There is a List of buildings. The building data has the format of [left, right, height] and it is massaged into two entries: [left, height, start] and [right, height, end] where start and end is a boolean type. So basically, it is [x, y, Boolean] type. (start = True, end = False)

Now I want to sort this list of [x, y, Boolean] according to x and while x is the same, the tie break will be Boolean type. If both x and Boolean type is the same, the next tie break is to sort by y and here is the tricky part, sorting of y will be ASC or DSC according to the Boolean flag.

So the list is to be sorted by x coordinates, then start followed by end. For the same x coordinates for start(True), the  y coordinates will be sorted descending while for the same x coordinates for end(False), the y coordinates will be sorted ascending.

Answer (score -1):

So we have to do sort two times and we will leave the primary sort by x (and boolean) coordinates last. We will do the sort where the direction of the sort change with the boolean flag first. 
Here it is:

`data.sort(key=lambda k: -k[1] if k[2] else k[1])`

then it will be followed by the primary sorting:

`data.sort(key=lambda k: (k[0], -k[2]))`

Here is the complete code with input.

```
def main():
    sol = Solution()  # None
    arg1 = [[1,3,4],[3,4,4],[2,6,2],[8,11,4],[7,9,3],[10,11,2]]
    r = sol.getSkyline(arg1)
    print(r)


class Solution:

    def getSkyline(self, buildings: List[List[int]]) -> List[List[int]]:
        if not buildings: return []
        data = []
        def compare(x, start):
            print(x, start)
            return (x, start)
        for building in buildings:
            data.append([building[0], building[2], True])
            data.append([building[1], building[2], False])
        data.sort(key=lambda k: -k[1] if k[2] else k[1])
        data.sort(key=lambda k: (k[0], -k[2]))
        return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the output:

[1, 4, True]

[2, 2, True]

[3, 4, True]

[3, 4, False]

[4, 4, False]

[6, 2, False]

[7, 3, True]

[8, 4, True]

[9, 3, False]

[10, 2, True]

[11, 2, False]

[11, 4, False]

Comment: Why can't we combine the two sorts?